# PHP select Specific Data

Tags: php, sql, select

Ok, I have this program sorta like a calendar with events. Users Upload events and the information are stored in a database to their respective Columns. eg(Event_Names: Name of the event)

What I want help with is pulling these info using specific values.

I managed to store the month and days in the month where there's an event like this:

```
if ( !mysql_select_db( "Events", $database ) )
            die( "Could not open Events database </body></html>" );

            foreach($months as $month => $arr) {

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posted_events WHERE Month_ = '$month' ") 
                    or die ('Error updating database because: '.mysql_error());

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                $months[$month][] =  $row['DayNum']; 


    }
}
```

But this just stores the month with all the days respective to that month where there's an event. But how could I store other stuff like the name of the event, the start and end time of the event, all the other stiff pertaining to the event which i have stored in the database.

I'm sure this is something simple, but I'm new to programming so it's gonna be difficult for me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Save all the information in `posted_events` with additional columns like `name` ,`start date` etc

Comment: example in code please? and would they be respective to specific dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( !mysql_select_db( "Events", $database ) )
            die( "Could not open Events database </body></html>" );

            foreach($months as $month => $arr) {

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posted_events WHERE Month_ = '$month' ") 
                    or die ('Error updating database because: '.mysql_error());

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                $months[$month][$row['DayNum']] = array($row['name'], $row['startdate'] ,etc.); 


    }
}
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding, how about a multidimensional array like this?

Comment: so you're adding more arrays to the array month? And if i wanna get the time and name for say the event on Jan 12th, how to do it?

Comment: Yes, you would use $months['desireddaynum']['time'] and $months['desireddaynum']['name'] respectively.